# PHP send slack messages with attachments and variable values

Tags: php, string, variables, slack-api, slack

Trying to `send messages to slack`channels with `incoming webhooks` installed on them. `Attachments` needs to be sent along with the message and PHP variables holds these URLs. Similary, I want to send some `ID's` which are again hold in some PHP variables. Here is my `server side PHP` code:

```
<?php

$testplan_name = $_POST[plan]; //test plan name coming from the client
$url1 = $_POST[run_url]; //run url coming from the client
$url2 = $_POST[plan_url]; //plan url coming from the client
$room = "random"; 
$icon_url = ":ghost:";
$username = "Test";
$attachments = array([
            'fallback' => 'Hey! See this message',
            'pretext'  => 'Here is the plan name ${testplan_name}',
            'color'    => '#ff6600',
            'fields'   => array(
                [
                    'title' => 'Run URL',
                    'value' => 'url1',
                    'short' => true
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'Build URL',
                    'value' => 'url2',
                    'short' => true
                ]
            )
        ]);

$data = "payload=" . json_encode(array(         
        "channel"       =>  "#{$room}",
        "icon_emoji"    =>  $icon_url,
        "username"      =>  $username,
        "attachments"   =>  $attachments

    ));

$url = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXX/XXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //got from slack as a webhook URL

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo var_dump($result);
if($result === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

If you see in the `attachments` variable above, there is variable inside of `pretext` which tries to print the value of `${testplan_name}` declared at the top. However, it does not seem to work and the program is failed to post messages to slack channels. Similarly, I want to print values of `url1` and `url2` in the `attachments -> fields` values as can be seen above(the way I am trying to print). The program just works fine if I do not try to use any variables and get their values while posting messages. How do I print the values of these variables in messages?

`(slack is a messaging platform for teams, if you don't know)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead>

```
    $attachments = array([
        'fallback' => 'Hey! See this message',
        'pretext'  => 'Here is the plan name '.$testplan_name,
        'color'    => '#ff6600',
        'fields'   => array(
            [
                'title' => 'Run URL',
                'value' => $url1,
                'short' => true
            ],
            [
                'title' => 'Build URL',
                'value' => $url2,
                'short' => true
            ]
        )
    ]);
```